# Image loading and not loading at random, PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a single image with size of 35738 bytes, and I'm trying to display it. The problem is that 1 time out of 2 it doesn't load, and I honestly can't see what the problem is. At first I thought that it was the size problem, but then I tried loading a picture with size of 162240 bytes, and it loads perfectly fine everytime, so I really can't see why this specific picture isn't loading. Please take a look at my code:

**showOneImage.php**

```
<img src = 'uploads/48v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg'>
```

Comment: Is it always the same picture displayed? Is there PHP code involved in this? Can you post your Network tab from F12?

Comment: @DaveChen There's an error404 when the image doesn't load.

Comment: Can you check the source when that happens? Is it the same picture? Can you post your PHP involved in displaying this picture?

Comment: Yes. I can check the source when that happens. <img src = 'uploads/48v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg'> <---that's the source. There is no PHP involved in displaying this picture.

Comment: There's a favicon.ico involved. In initiator it seems to have that extension at the end.

Comment: In favicon.ico it says failed to load response data. @DaveChen

Comment: @durbnpoisn What do you mean?

Comment: Many servers have clusters that are synched up on a regular basis.  You could add a file to your server, and assume that the entire cluster is synched, when in fact, it hasn't.  It's just an idea...  Maybe you could try posting a direct link to the image, and see if WE can see it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The Content Download is 1.240 ms when the image loads. It's 0.231 ms when it doesn't load.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Here: http://randomcutegirls.com/moretest.php

Comment: @durbnpoisn It works 1 times out of 2, so if it works the first time, you have to refresh it a couple of times to see when it doesn't.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not clicking on "randomcutegirls" at work.  This will have to wait until later.

Comment: @durbnpoisn It's a picture of a cat...I'm not posting pictures of cute girls in testing phase...

Comment: @durbnpoisn It's just the cat picture. 90% of the internet is cat pictures.

Comment: @BigScar You know what's going on here?

Comment: oh.  ok.  Yes.  It's 2 cats, in fact.  So I can see it.  In other words, there doesn't appear to be a problem with your picture.

Comment: @DaveChen The Content Download is 1.240 ms when the image loads. It's 0.231 ms when it doesn't load.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Maybe you forgot about the part where I said that it works 1 time out of 2. Try refreshing it a few times, and you'll see when it won't work.

Comment: I did.  It never failed.

Comment: @durbnpoisn How many times did you refreshed it? And if it works for you, how come it doesn't work for me? I tried it at the school computer, and at my home computer, so it shouldn't be a problem of the computer....

Comment: I don't know.  But the image is fine:  http://randomcutegirls.com/uploads/48v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg  Could you post your PHP?

Comment: @durbnpoisn Also, you should check f12 under network. There's a 404 error for some reason.

Comment: @durbnpoisn There isn't any PHP code. For now. Just the single img tag.

Comment: Also that link is bringing me to this page instead for some reason http://call4joke.com/page/call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84112/discussion-between-durbnpoisn-and-frosty).

Comment: Its loading 100% of the time for me in Firefox and Chrome. What link I didn't see any link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving this over to chat, we have determined that, with some other strange behavior, that the server is responsible for the random activity.

That is, it seems that the server has been hacked with malware and is causing some random redirects.  The lesson of using a free shared host.

Comment: I can confidently say that the image didn't show up half the time was because it redirected to that random redirect page half the time it tried to load the image.